# "The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.String' and 'System.String'." -- Really?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

When trying to run the following code:

```
    Expression<Func<string, string>> stringExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(
        Expression.Add(
            stringParam,
            Expression.Constant("A")
        ),
        new List<ParameterExpression>() { stringParam }
    );

    string AB = stringExpression.Compile()("B");
```

I get the error referenced in the title: "The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.String' and 'System.String'." Is that really the case? Obviously in C# it works. Is doing `string s = "A" + "B"` in C# special syntactic sugar that the expression compiler doesn't have access to?

Comment: Followup I guess: Why doesn't the expression compiler do the same magic as the C# compiler?

Comment: To answer the follow-up, why should it? While there are languages that use `+` as a concatenation operator as well as an addition operator on numeric types, that isn't universal (other common concat operators include `.`, `||`, `&`, `<<`) and even those that do use `+` call it *concatenation* in that context. The `Expression.Add` method is called `Add` and one can expect it to do addition and not to do anything else (unless a type has overloaded `+` but then since that's internally a method called `op_addition` the type is claiming it is an *add*).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's absolutely right, yes. There is no such operator - the C# compiler converts `string + string` into a call to `string.Concat`. (This is important, because it means that `x + y + z` can be converted into `string.Concat(x, y, z)` which avoids creating intermediate strings pointlessly.

Have a look at the docs for [string operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986396.aspx) - only `==` and `!=` are defined by the framework.

Answer (score 8):

This just caught me out too, and as Jon points out in his answer, the C# compiler converts `string + string` into `string.Concat`. There is an [overload of the Expression.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339231%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that allows you to specify the "add" method to use.

```
var concatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }); 
var addExpr = Expression.Add(Expression.Constant("hello "),Expression.Constant("world"), concatMethod);
```

You might want to change the `string.Concat` method to use the correct [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Proving this works:

```
Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(addExpr).Compile()());
```

Will output:

> hello world

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, it's a surprise isn't it!!! The compiler replaces it with a call to **String.Concat**.