# Linq Expression Tree - Concatenate Array of values

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am currently working with a .net core (vnext) solution which is using linq and entity framework core.

We are using Microsoft.Linq.Translations to store computed column definitions as a lambda expression so that they can then be injected into our statements when needed. An example of a computed definition is as follows:

```
private static readonly CompiledExpression<Model, string> fullNameExpression =
        aTranslation<Model>.Expression(e => e.FullName, e => $"{e.FirstName} {e.LastName} ({e.Code})");
```

and to consume/execute it:

```
var list = context.Set<Model>().Where(e => e.FullName.Contains("Bob")).WithTranslations();
```

This all "techincally" works fine....as in the correct result gets bound back to the entity models, however the work is being done in memory instead of building the query out in SQL. This is a problem as our data models may end up with millions of rows of data and doing this in memory would be troublesome.

This is what we end up with at the moment:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Model,System.Boolean]>(Model $e) {
.Call (.Call System.String.Format(
    "{0} {1} ({2})",
    $e.FirstName,
    $e.LastName,
    $e.Code)).Contains("Bob")
```

}

Like I said, this works but results in the task being performed in memory instead of SQL. The query gets generated something like:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Code FROM Model
```

So, if i changed the computed definition to the following (note i am simply building a string manually instead of using string.format:

```
private static readonly CompiledExpression<Model, string> fullNameExpression =
        aTranslation<Model>.Expression(e => e.FullName, e => e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName + "(" + e.Code + ")");
```

This produces a lambda expression like the following:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Model,System.Boolean]>(Model $e) {
.Call ($e.FirstName + " " + $e.LastName + " (" + $e.Code + ")").Contains("Bob")}
```

This will work and build the SQL query out correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM Model WHERE (FirstName + ' ' + LastName + '(' + Code + ')') LIKE '%bob%'
```

So, short of changing the way the computed definitions are written/defined, I am trying to write a layer which takes a definition written using the string format linq expression and replaces that expression with the second type (like a string concatenation)

I have started writing this layer by intercepting the string format expression and building a list/array of member and constant expressions i.e. 
FirstName,
" ",
LastName,
" ("
etc....

I tried using a string concat approach by looping through the values and evaluating the left and right expressions but this ends up with something else that didn't work:

```
.Call System.String.Concat(
.Call System.String.Concat(
    .Call System.String.Concat(
        .Call System.String.Concat(
            $e.FirstName,
            " "),
        $e.LastName),
    " ("),
$e.Code)
```

Now, i'm stuck as to how to convert that list of expressions to produce this sort of expression:

```
 .Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Model,System.Boolean]>(Model $e) {
.Call ($e.FirstName + " " + $e.LastName + " (" + $e.Code + ")").Contains("Bob")}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

----------------- Edit -------------

Code tried so far. I have left out the building of the "concatArgs" variable for brevity. It is simply a List containing the MemberExpression and ConstantExpression type.

```
Expression expr = GenerateStringConcat(concatArgs[0], concatArgs[1]);
for(int i = 2; i < concatArgs.Count; i++)
    expr = GenerateStringConcat(expr, concatArgs[i]);
```

and the method being called is show below

```
private Expression GenerateStringConcat(Expression left, Expression right) {
        return Expression.Call(
             null,
             typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) }),
             new[] { left, right });
}
```

Comment: Write the expression manually in a query that works. Then, decompile the assembly (or use Roslyn online) to see what expression tree the C# compiler generated. That's a template that you can use.

Comment: Post the code you have tried so we can try adjusting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out!

The comment from @usr prompted me to delve into the syntax tree a little more and see how the code was being compiled down. I used the Syntax Visualizer built into VS2015 under "View -> Other Windows -> Syntax Visualizer"

When breaking apart a standard linq expression of the desired result this suggested that behind the scenes this was compiling down to a BinaryOperator which seemed odd...

Initially i tried replacing my string.concat calls with:

```
BinaryExpression.Add(concatArgs[0], concatArgs[1])
```

However, this resulted in the following error:

> The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.String'
>   and 'System.String'

Which lead me to this article/post:

["The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.String' and 'System.String'." -- Really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027384/the-binary-operator-add-is-not-defined-for-the-types-system-string-and-syste)

with this suggested overload:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339231%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Basically, behind the scenes this all ends up getting converted into a string.concat call anyway, however using the BinaryExpression.Add method seems to allow linq to work this out at runtime and only use one call to string.concat? maybe the "params object[]"?

Anyhow, changing my GenerateStringConcat method to the following has done the trick:

```
private Expression GenerateStringConcat(Expression left, Expression right)
{
    return BinaryExpression.Add(left, right, typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) }));
}
```